# I need a dynamic report for symfony 3

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.4

I need to know a dynamic report for symfony 3 but I can't find nothing. Can you recomend any bundle or I can do it manually?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) carefully.

Answer (score 0):

if you search about dynamic Report Bundle for dynamic reports from databases try this [bundle](https://github.com/TechPromux/TechPromuxDynamicReportBundle)

Comment: I test this bundle but it is abandoned has no configuration or documentation.